# Vectorize for loop with interdependent iterations

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

r is a vector:

```
23 1 24 5 4 3 7 8
```

L is a vector.

```
L=
 2, 4, 6, 5, 3
```

I am trying to vectorize this piece of code. Since iterations are interdependent (i.e. `prev_weight = prev_weight - weight_from`), I cannot figure out a good way of vectorization. The goal is obviously to minimize the execution time.

```
    total_weight = sum(r(L));
    prev_weight = total_weight;

    len=length(L);

    dist = 0.0;
    for i=2:len-1
        from=L(i);
        to=L(i+1);
        dist = dist + d(from,to) * prev_weight;
        weight_from = r(from);
        prev_weight = prev_weight - weight_from;
    end
```

Comment: What's `d`, `from` , `to`?

Comment: @Divakar: d is the distance matrix (2-dim. array). from and to are defined as L(i) and L(i+1), accordingly. This code estimates weighted_ trip length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dependency can be *traced back* to a [`cummulative sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) operation, which forms the basis of the vectorized solution listed below -

```
%// Vectorized way to get "d(from,to)" across all iterations with SUB2IND
vals = d(sub2ind(size(d),L(2:end-1),L(3:end)))

%// Vectorized way to get "r(from)" as we already have all "from" indices
weight_from1 = r(L(2:end-1))

%// Magic happens here as we trace the dependency with cumsum and thus
%// get all previous weights in one go
prev_weight1 = total_weight - [0 cumsum(weight_from1(1:end-1))]

%// Finally get the distance with elementwise multiplication and summing
%// being simulated with dot product
dist_out = vals*prev_weight1.'
```

Comment: I checked your solution. It looks nice. Just one question. While weight_from1 is the same as in my solution, prev_weight1 is slightly different from my prev_weight. Why does this happen?

Comment: Also what if length(L) is less than or equal to 2?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos So for `len <=2` since it won't go into the loop, you can check for such a case with `len >2`:  *do this vectorized solution*, else *0*. I think the slight mis-match is because of the cummulative operation when performed on really huge array, when it tries to add one element to an already accumulated huge number.

Comment: I measured total execution time of a vectorized solution and it was even greater than my original solution. Vectorization staff is really annoying. It's much easier to implement things right in Java or C in order to later avoid problems with a large execution time. But thank you anyway for a nice solution.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Wow really? I was really expecting the vectorized solution to be much faster! Hmm, I am surprised a bit!